# Managing version control of Erwin file changes with multiple environments

Tags: version-control, erwin

What is the easiest way to manage three environments (DEV, QA and PROD) within a single Erwin file or multiple Erwin files?  The Erwin file is separated by subject area, so I'm not sure reverse engineering is a viable option.  We perform migrations every day, but they don't always conform to what is in Erwin, so we have a difficult time showing our end-users what is in QA and what is in PROD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erwin is a great tool for managing logical schemas but rarely being used to manage code (package, procedure, etc…) and content management.

Some editions of Erwin have a built-in version control, but again only for the artifacts being managed by Erwin.

[TeamWork by dbMaestro](http://bit.ly/116qyMW) (which I'm part of) does a real Database Version Control and Database Deployment.
As many of our customers do have Erwin, we recommended them to use Erwin on a dedicate environment so the flow will be like Erwin -> Dev -> QA -> …

Changes being made in the Erwin environment are promoted to Dev using TeamWork Deployment Manager and the Dev, QA, etc… environments are managed by [TeamWork version control](http://bit.ly/112uxKC).
This gives you the ability to have logical design by Erwin and a real database version control for the physical layer by TeamWork. I hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

CA has a tool called Model Manager that may be able to help you out here.